# How to individually call a form to a html in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

First time creating a webapp in django. please bear with me.

So I have this code in my html:

```
<h1><font color="Orange" face="Borda">{{ template_title }}</h1>
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
<font color="Orange" face="Borda" style="background-color: transparent;">{{ form }}</font>>
<input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
</form>
```

now inside {{ form }} is all the views and forms. now what I want to do is to specifically call it individually (with style).

for example if I have:

```
email=CharField()
username=CharField()
```

and I wanted to call them in my html as:

```
<label class="sr-only" for="r-form-first-name">**EMAIL/USERNAME**</label>
<input type="text" name="r-form-first-name" placeholder="First name..." class="r-form-first-name form-control" id="r-form-first-name">
```

How do I do that? I already have a bootstrap template prepared for my login but other documentation suggest I use crispy forms, which I dont want to. Please tell me how if there is other ways of calling it.

Answer (score -1):

Since it's your first time building a django app, i suggest you take your time building it, try reading relative doc pages for the parts you're working with.
Here's an example from the docs (tailored for your case):

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.username.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
    {{ form.username }}
</div>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually